# How can I save VLC snapshots in the video's path?

Tags: vlc-media-player, snapshot

I know you can set the path where snapshots are saved in VLC Player's preferences. What I want is to save the snapshots not all in one fixed directory, but in the video's directory, provided of course that the video isn't on a read-only medium like a DVD.
I know this is possible, but I forget which symbol I should enter in the save path.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Preferences --> Video --> Video snapshots`

Change directory to `.`
Like so:
[image]

Comment: I'll be damned, learned something today! Thanks, this has been bugging me subconsciously for a long time :)

Comment: Yeah, that's it. How could I ever forget? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Note this doesn't work for Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm guessing, will a `./` work on Mac instead?

Comment: Been wondering how to do this for years!

Comment: @SaaranshGarg - Not seeing any variation on that kind of theme that works. Unless it's an actual address it does nothing. Remove it & it reverts to its default. It won't even accept Mac-shorthand for 'user' ie ~/anything, it demands a full address or none.

Answer (score 1):

My findings when using "." as directory in VLC snapshot settings with
VLC 3.0.20 on **Windows** 11 and VLC 3.0.16 on **Linux** Mint 21.2

When starting VLC directly from the command line (Windows) or terminal (Linux Mint) with a video file as argument, it uses the startup/current directory as working directory. This also seems to be the case on both platforms when using the --started-from-file option.

Using the dot "." will work on **Windows** when using the VLC desktop version on Windows and using **explorer** to start videos though file associations (double clicking on a video file) .
Explorer will start VLC with the directory of the video file as working directory.

Using the dot "." on **Linux Mint** using **nemo** does not work, changes have to made.
Instead of launching vlc when clicking on a video file using nemo, a script file that changes into the directory of the video file needs to be launched first:

- sudo edit the file `/usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop` and
  find the line starting with "Exec" around the end of the file.
- change `/usr/bin/vlc` to `/usr/bin/vlccustom` in that line, save file, quit editor.
- `cd /usr/bin`
- create the script file `sudo touch vlccustom`
- make it executable `sudo chmod +x vlccustom`
- sudo edit the file `vlccustom`
- add the lines shown below, save file and quit the editor

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$2"
DIR=$(dirname $2)
echo "$DIR"
cd "$DIR"

/usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file $2
```

Note: The `vlc.desktop` file setting `Terminal` `=true` or `=false` comes in handy while testing.